# Test CRUD function in Playframework unit tests using ScalaTest

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I created some CRUD functions with scala and I want to test them using unit test. For example I want to test the send method:

```
class MyFunctionDAO @Inject() (db: DB) {

  def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("myCollection")

  def save(myObject: MyObject): Future[Either[String, UUID]] = {
    collection.insert(myObject).map {
      case result if result.ok == true => Right(myObject._id)
      case result => Left(result.message)
    }
  }
}
```

How can I proceed? Any example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ScalaMock](http://scalamock.org/) to mock your `db` instance and set expectations and returned values. There is a [page](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects) in ScalaTest doc about that.

*Following example describes approach and may have issues*

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class MyFunctionDAOSpec extends FlatSpec with MockFactory {
  val db = mock[DB]
  val col = mock[JSONCollection]
  (col.insert _) expects (myObj) returning (okResult)
  (col.insert _) expects (myObj2) returning (failResult)
  (db.collection _) expects ("myCollection") returning (col) 
  //...

  val dao = new MyFunctionDAO(db)

  "DAO" should "return Right" in {
    dao.save(myObj) should be (Right(myObj._id))
  }

  it should "return Left" in {
    dao.save(myObj2) should be (Left("my error message"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively new into testing, admittedly, but I'll share my opinion as it's being forged. It is my perception that CRUD operations should not be unit-tested. They should be integration tested instead. Because when we unit-test the API method, we are trying to test that it abides its contract. But what exactly does it mean that "this method should add this entity with those properties to the DB"? Say, the method contains some logic that parses the incoming DTO and converts it to DB entities/relations/etc.; but we ought not test for some expected result of conversion, because it's "how" the method works, not "what" it does: it's a test of implementation, not contract; even more, this whole logic is only needed because we use that DB model, and not some other model, and it has nothing to do with CRUD operation itself.

However we probably should not leave conversion logics untested, especially if it's not quite trivial. So, we could test it directly: instead of testing write(x)=f(convert(x)) for actually trying to write x, with convert(x) being private part of implementation (thus skipped from tests), we can skip unit-testing f() - leaving that for integration tests - and test directly convert(x).

Comment: Let me add yet another argument. It we define write(x)=db_write(convert(x)), how are we supposed to unit-test write(x) at all? Convert(x) is out of scope - for this test we consider it something that can be mocked, not tested -  and db_write is also out of scope because it's some library's functionality - and suddenly there's no logic left to test.